# how to get parameter value in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

am using ajax call function in codeigniter view.php

```
$.ajax({            
    type: 'post',
    url: '../user_controller/insert_user',
    data: { username : $("#name").val(), },
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }       
});
```

I want value of 'username' parameter in controller, how can I get this value?

Comment: `$this->input->post('username');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({            
            type: 'post',
            url: '../user_controller/insert_user',
            data: { 'username' : $("#name").val()},
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }       
        });
```

in `user_controller/insert_user` action

In core php

```
echo $_POST['username'];
```

OR as in CI

```
$this->input->post('username');
```

Will give you the value of `username`

Comment: Or `$this->input->post('username')`, as per CI

Comment: Correct @Damien Pirsy . Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

```
$this->input->post('username');
```

You can also use $_POST['username'] but they don't suggest that, plus you should always use `if (isset($_POST['username']))` or `if (!empty($_POST['username']))` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this in your controller

```
function insert_user(){
  $user=$this->input->post('username');
}
```